# Reducing Tx_Power for mobile hotspot - hostapd.conf

Tags: adb, root-access, battery-life, wifi-hotspot

I am using rooted Samsung J2 pro with Marshmallow 6.0.1. My mobile hotspot uses a lot of battery. And this battery usage is reported by Android OS process by Smart Manager.

I have reduced the **tx_power** manually from **4** to **1** in **hostapd.conf** located under **/data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf** but it gets overwritten whenever I switch on the hotspot.

How can I make it permanent or is there a way to change **tx_power** through **adb**?

[image]